# Find and replace string inside BLOB for Work or Excel File

Tags: oracle, plsql, replace, blob

I have a requirement to find and replace hyperlinks which are outdated in several thousand documents stored in the database.

Currently I have some functions that will covert a BLOB to a CLOB do a find and replace and then convert back to a BLOB.

The end results however don't leave the file in its original state e.g. I have a word doc stored I find hyperlink [www.google.co.uk](http://www.google.co.uk) and replace and the BLOB data is no longer of type word document and I can't open it.

Is there a recommended method to do the above.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Word and Excel files are not text files that you can just replace text on and that will definitely not work with a `BLOB`. **docx** and **xlsx** files are actually zip files (try changing the file extension and unzipping to see for yourself) that contain an XML definition of the document. So you will need to:

1. Unzip the file
2. Convert the file that needs changing from a `BLOB` to a `CLOB`
3. Modify the contents of the proper XML file
4. Convert the file back to a `BLOB` from a `CLOB`
5. Add the modified file back into the zip file

I have written the code below as an example on how to do a replacement to a **docx** file. For **xlsx** files, each Excel sheet is contained within a different XML file so you will need to modify the code slightly to get it to work with both file types.

The code does use the [APEX_ZIP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aeapi/APEX_ZIP.html#GUID-270BFF3A-5FB1-4089-894E-978608F9BD87) package which greatly simplifies working with zip files and also makes the example code a bit clearer as to what is going on. If you do not have APEX installed, you will need to figure out how to do the unzipping/rezipping of the files using the Oracle packages you have.

```sql
DECLARE
    l_old_file       BLOB;
    l_new_file       BLOB;
    l_files          apex_zip.t_files;
    l_document       BLOB;
    l_clob           CLOB;
    l_dest_offsset   INTEGER;
    l_src_offsset    INTEGER;
    l_lang_context   INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
    l_warning        INTEGER;
BEGIN
    -- Get the blob you want to "correct"
    SELECT blob_content
      INTO l_old_file
      FROM apex_application_temp_files
     WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

    -- Get a list of all the file names contained within the zip
    l_files := apex_zip.get_files (l_old_file);

    -- Loop through all the files adding each one to the new zip
    FOR i IN l_files.FIRST .. l_files.LAST
    LOOP
        l_document := apex_zip.get_file_content (l_old_file, l_files (i));

        IF l_files (i) = 'word/document.xml'
        THEN
            -- if the file name is word/document.xml then make the changes to it
            
            DBMS_LOB.createTemporary (lob_loc => l_clob, cache => FALSE);

            l_dest_offsset := 1;
            l_src_offsset := 1;

            DBMS_LOB.converttoclob (dest_lob       => l_clob,
                                    src_blob       => l_document,
                                    amount         => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
                                    dest_offset    => l_dest_offsset,
                                    src_offset     => l_src_offsset,
                                    blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
                                    lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                    warning        => l_warning);

            --------------------
            -- This is where you would do any replacements
            --------------------
            l_clob := REPLACE (l_clob, 'www.google.co.uk', 'www.google.com');
            --------------------

            l_dest_offsset := 1;
            l_src_offsset := 1;

            DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB (dest_lob       => l_document,
                                    src_clob       => l_clob,
                                    amount         => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
                                    dest_offset    => l_dest_offsset,
                                    src_offset     => l_src_offsset,
                                    blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
                                    lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                    warning        => l_warning);
        END IF;

        apex_zip.add_file (l_new_file, l_files (i), l_document);
    END LOOP;

    apex_zip.finish (l_new_file);
    --Do whatever you want with the "new" file here
END;
```

Comment: I seem to have an issue the blob file appears to corrupt e.g. the Word Document file will not open and reference's permission errors, space issues and or using a text recovery tool.

Comment: There could be several reasons for this. How are you unzipping/re-zipping the files? If you download the "new file", change the extension to `.zip` and attempt to unzip it, does it unzip successfully and do the modified XML files appear as you would expect?

Comment: Thanks for the response, currently all I have done is directly update the tables BLOB value after the part you mentioned for apex_zip.finish using l_new_file. I have done a dbms_output to show the xml string before and after replace on the clob and can't see any differences.