# Find worksheet name in blob Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, blob

There is a blob test.xlsb file in Oracle table1.data. In test.xlsb there is a worksheet 'Hello'. But script

```
SELECT
    CASE DBMS_LOB.instr(t.data, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('Hello'))
    WHEN 0 THEN 'No such line' ELSE 'Okay' END res
FROM table1 t;
```

return 'No such line'. Why? How can we solve the problem "does *.xlsb file have a worksheet with a specific [sheet.name]?" Of course, we assume that we cannot just open the file in Excel and see if there is a such worksheet.

Comment: You are probably unable to find that string because a .xlsb file is basically a compressed ZIP file.  You will have to decompress the file and read whichever file within this ZIP file contains the sheet names.  However, I can't help but feel that the database is the wrong place to be doing this kind of thing.

Comment: @LukeWoodward , thanks for your opinion. I'll see about decompression. But things are as they are. And there is a need to filter a lot of .xlsb files by the name of the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is similar to [Find and replace string inside BLOB for Work or Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809355/find-and-replace-string-inside-blob-for-work-or-excel-file)

```
DECLARE
    l_old_file       BLOB;
    l_new_file       BLOB;
    l_files          apex_zip.t_files;
    l_document       BLOB;
    l_clob           CLOB;
    l_dest_offsset   INTEGER;
    l_src_offsset    INTEGER;
    l_lang_context   INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
    l_warning        INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT t.data INTO  l_old_file 
    FROM table1 t;

    -- Get a list of all the file names contained within the zip
    l_files := apex_zip.get_files (l_old_file);

    -- Loop through all the files adding each one to the new zip
    FOR i IN l_files.FIRST .. l_files.LAST
    LOOP
        l_document := apex_zip.get_file_content (l_old_file, l_files (i));
        DBMS_LOB.createTemporary (lob_loc => l_clob, cache => FALSE);
        l_dest_offsset := 1;
        l_src_offsset := 1;

        DBMS_LOB.converttoclob (dest_lob       => l_clob,
                                src_blob       => l_document,
                                amount         => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
                                dest_offset    => l_dest_offsset,
                                src_offset     => l_src_offsset,
                                blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
                                lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                warning        => l_warning);

            result := INSTR(l_clob, str)
            EXIT WHEN res > 0;

            l_dest_offsset := 1;
            l_src_offsset := 1;

            DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB (dest_lob       => l_document,
                                    src_clob       => l_clob,
                                    amount         => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
                                    dest_offset    => l_dest_offsset,
                                    src_offset     => l_src_offsset,
                                    blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
                                    lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                    warning        => l_warning);
    END LOOP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(res);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select *
  from table1
 where dbms_lob.instr (t1, -- the blob column of table
                   utl_raw.cast_to_raw ('Hello'), -- the search string 
                   1, -- starting pointoffset
                   1 -- the which occurance 
                 ) > 0; -- location of text
```

Comment: can you open the document on notepad than search the text you are searching? I always using this script without any problem.

Comment: I want to do all checks at the database level.I'm pretty sure there's a worksheet 'Hello' in the test.xlsb and the script above does not work. I want a scalable solution